# Генерация случайных комбинаций чисел

Tags: python-3.x, случайные-числа

Вопрос - как сгенерировать 1000 уникальных комбинаций для лотереи 6x36, чтобы выполнялось условие:

- каждая новая генерируемая комбинация не повторяла любую из ранее сгенерированных комбинаций
- серии/группы комбинаций не должны содержать явных закономерностей, по которым можно было бы с большой точностью спрогнозировать последующую комбинацию после серии/группы.

### Первоначальный пост (для истории)

Требуется сгенерировать 1 000 000 случайных неповторяющихся комбинаций из 6 уникальных цифр от 1 по 36 включительно (лотерея).

Ниже приведенный рабочий код.  Перед добавлением комбинации в список делается проверка, есть ли такая комбинация в списке. Как показывает статистика повторяющиеся комбинации встречаются довольно часто. Как "улучшить" генерацию случайных чисел и комбинаций?

```
import pandas as pd 
import argparse as ap
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from collections import Counter
import json
from random import randint
from itertools import chain
import operator
from functools import reduce
from Crypto.Random import random


def ArgParser():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--draws', help='Test result', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

def main():

    testDraw = 105
    sampleSize = 20 
    ballsLen = 6
    predictLen = 1000000
    maxBall = 36

    testDrawBalls = [ 3, 6, 11, 21, 26, 35, 16]

    predictions = []
    count = 1 
    while len(predictions) < predictLen:

        balls = []

        while len(balls) < ballsLen:
            ball = random.randint(1,maxBall)
            if (ball not in balls):
                balls.append(ball)

        balls.sort()
        if(balls in predictions):
            print(balls)
            continue

        predictions.append(balls)


    p = pd.DataFrame(predictions)
    hints = p.T.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & testDrawBalls)).value_counts().sort_index()
    print("---------------------")
    print(hints)
    print(len(predictions))

    print('The End')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random  

ballsLen = 6
predictLen = 1000000
maxBall = 36

predictions = set()

while len(predictions) < predictLen:

    balls = set()      
    while len(balls) < ballsLen:
        balls.add(random.randint(1, maxBall))

    predictions.add(tuple(sorted(balls)))


print(len(predictions))
1000000

print(tuple(predictions)[0:2])
((10, 13, 28, 30, 31, 33), (3, 9, 14, 18, 27, 32))

print(tuple(predictions)[999998:1000001])
((3, 9, 12, 30, 31, 33), (18, 19, 20, 25, 28, 29))
```

Comment: Всем спасибо за интересные решения. Мой вопрос остался открытым - каким способом лучше генерировать "случайные комбинации"? Что лучше генерировать все комбинации и потом их перемешивать или лучше генерировать в отдельности каждое число каждой комбинации. Вопрос в не производительности и размере и красоте кода, а в генерации "максимально случайных" комбинации.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, Оба варианта являются одинаково случайными. Многие комбинации у вас по любому будут похожи, поскольку вам нужен миллион комбинаций, а их возможное количество всего меньше двух миллионов. Так что миллион совсем непохожих комбинаций наковырять не получится, почти любой элемент в любом случае будет иметь по пять общих чисел с несколькими другими элементами.

Comment: @Александр - сокртаим число комбинаций до 1000. Оба варианта будут одинаково хорошими? Пример - берем отсортированную колоду карт.  Тасуем карты. Смотрим результат. Карты будет перемещанны, но все равно найдутся несколько карт, которые сохранят свою первоначальную  очередность. В случае shuffle преподалагаю, что результат будет аналогичен с колодой карт.  Другой пример датчик случайных чисел генериет набор числе {2, 30, 17, 1} и {1, 17, 2, 30}. Это разный набор данных вроде бы, но если их отсортировать, то мы получим одинаковый набор чисел.  А хотелось бы, чтобы наборы не пересекались вообще.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Проблема в том, что истинно случайное последовательность всегда содержит какие-то подпоследовательности, в которых кажется присутствие закономерности. Про это довольно много написано. Сейчас попробую найти пару статей, которые я видел на эту тему.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev https://habr.com/ru/post/343482/

Comment: @YuriyTigiev https://habr.com/ru/post/320296/

Comment: @YuriyTigiev поэтому если вы хотите, чтобы у вас не встречались такие совпадения, то совершенно случайная генерация вам как раз таки и не подходит.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev а что вам подходит - можно сказать, только после того как вы сформулируете чёткие требования того, что хотите получить. Причём, реалистичные требования, так как миллион непохожих комбинаций в принципе нельзя сгенерировать, если их всего меньше двух миллионов.

Comment: Для примера я хочу сгенерировать 1000 лотерейных билетов 6 из 36, в которых не наблюдалось подпоследовательности, и/или ни одна из 1000 сгенерированных комбинаций не должна повторять предыдущие.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, думаю, будет лучше это оформить отдельным вопросом. И постарайтесь как можно более подробно расписать все требования. Например - что вы считаете "подпоследовательностью"? Если в билете содержатся два соседних числа (17 и 18) - то это уже "подпоследовательность" или ещё нет? Если два билета не совпадают полностью, но 5 из 6 чисел в них одинаковые - то это вам подходит или нет?

Answer (score 3):

Логично, что у вас будет много повторов.

Ведь всего возможное число сочетаний по 6 элементов из 36 будет равно

`36! / ((36-6)! * 6!)`

Что составляет 1947792. То есть ближе к концу перебора у вас каждая вторая попытка будет холостая. И для каждой попытки у вас происходит проверка вхождения в список длинной сотни тысяч элементов - это очень "тяжёлая" процедура.

Поэтому гораздо разумнее поступить так:

1). Сгенерировать сначала все возможные варианты. Их меньше двух миллионов, они сгенерятся быстро и займут не очень много места в памяти.

2). Потом перемешать эту последовательность. Эта операция потяжелее, но она выполняется всего один раз, поэтому много времени не займёт.

3). После этого от перемешанной последовательности откусываем первые миллион элементов.

```
import itertools
import random

NUMBERS = list(range(1, 36+1))
MILLION = 10**6

all_variants = list(itertools.combinations(NUMBERS, 6))
random.shuffle(all_variants)

print(all_variants[:MILLION])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def getCombo(maxBall, ballsLen):
    balls = []
    while len(balls) < ballsLen:
        ball = random.randint(1, ballsLen)
        if ball not in balls:
            balls.append(ball)
    return sorted(balls)

def comboToStr(combo):
    return ' '.join([str(ball) for ball in combo])

def strToCombo(comboStr):
    return [int(ball) for ball in comboStr.split()]

def getPrediction(predLen):
    predictions = set()
    while len(predictions) < predLen:
        predictions.add(comboToStr(getCombo))
    return [strToCombo(combo) for combo in predictions]
```

Идея в том, чтобы изначально строить set комбинаций (наборов шаров), что гораздо дешевле, чем на каждой итерации проверять вхождение комбинации в список. Преобразование в строку - чтобы можно было построить set.

Плюс, можно чуть подправить, чтобы не считать длину set'а на каждой итерации, например как-то так:

```
def getPrediction(predLen):
    predictions = set()
    while len(predictions) < predLen:
        for _ in range(predLen - len(predictions):
            predictions.add(comboToStr(getCombo))
    return [strToCombo(combo) for combo in predictions]
```

Comment: Не стоит городить преобразование в строку и обратно. Достаточно из getCombo возвращать не список, а кортеж. Кортежи можно складывать в set.

Comment: @Александр не знал. Если так, то конечно, это проще. Первая мысль была как у Вас, но посчитал общее к-во комбинаций как `36! / (36-6)!` а это многовато.